# these settings are enforced by adminstrator proxy settings chrome

Tags: google-chrome, proxy

unable to open any web page in chrome it shows "waiting for proxy tunnel" but doesn't load. I can't even change the proxy settings it says "These settings are enforced by administrator"

[image] .

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on what you are asking?

Comment: When I open my Google chrome and try to load any web page it shows blank and a message displays at bottom left saying waiting for proxy tunnel...it is shown in fst image....

Comment: Some said solution was to change ur proxy settings but I am unable to change as its saying "these settings are enforced by adminstrator" which is shown in 2nd image..

Comment: Sorry, but I think I got you wrong in the first place. This doesn't seem to be programming related, so is off-topic for stackoverflow. How about trying other stack exchange sites?